# Android : Listview data is not being passed in another activity

Tags: android, listview

I have made a listview and inflated it from database. And i have set up an `onclicklistener` on listview item using:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_books);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    call=(Button)findViewById(R.id.call);
    userDbHelper = new UserDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
    sqLiteDatabase = userDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = userDbHelper.getInformation(sqLiteDatabase);
    listDataAdapter = new ListDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_layout);
    final TextView txt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.pr);
    listView.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
           Intent in=new Intent(Books.this,List1.class);
            TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.pr);
            String getPrice=txt.getText().toString();
            in.putExtra("getPrice",getPrice);
           startActivity(in);
        }
    });

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            id = cursor.getInt(0);
            category = cursor.getString(1);
            name = cursor.getString(2);
            phone = cursor.getString(3);
            price = cursor.getString(4);
            desc = cursor.getString(5);
            photo = cursor.getBlob(6);

            //Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photo, 0, photo.length);
            DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(id,category, name, phone, price, desc, photo);
            listDataAdapter.add(dataProvider);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

and in `List1.class` i am trying to retrieve id from database whose listview is clicked so that i can inflate other layout according to that. How can it be done? 

List1.class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list1);
      TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.pr);
      String getPrice=txt.getText().toString();
      userDbHelper = new UserDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
      sqLiteDatabase = userDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
      ImageView img1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image2);
      Intent in=getIntent();
      Cursor cursor=userDbHelper.getContact(getPrice,sqLiteDatabase);
      if(cursor.moveToFirst())
      {
          String NAME=cursor.getString(0);
          String PHONE=cursor.getString(1);
          String DESC=cursor.getString(2);
          byte[] PHOTO=cursor.getBlob(3);
          Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photo, 0, photo.length);
          img1.setImageBitmap(bmp);
      }
    userDbHelper=new UserDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
    sqLiteDatabase=userDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
      price1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Price);

}
```

Comment: then you need to pass a value in your `onClickListener` when starting your activity. And then retrieving that value to hand over to your DB code. If I am understanding you correctly.

Comment: I dont see where you are passing any value while starting your intent.

Comment: tried `intent.putExtra`   also  retrieving id with

Comment: I dont think you are getting your price value correctly in your `onClick`. to get the text on a Listview do something like so `String text = (String) lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the ListView ID/Position to be passed:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

       Intent in=new Intent(Books.this,List1.class);
         ///String text = (String) lv.getItemAtPosition(i); //Or you can get the text for the List item you clicked on. 
         in.putExtra("ID_VAR", i); /// ID clicked
       startActivity(in);
     }
 });
```

Get the data in your `onCreate`:

```
Intent mIntent = getIntent();
int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("ID_VAR", 0);
System.out.println("Debugging:" + intValue); ///Debugging
```

Comment: yeah it worked `List1.class` layout got opened but still corresponding image is not getting set. :/

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `Corresponding Image` - I thought you are trying to get the clicked List Item value  > Pass it over to `List1`,  and use it to get corresponding data / Inflate Other layout based on the value

Comment: Yeah, that is what i am trying ..In ListView there is a image also .. and in second layout no data is getting set.

Comment: Ok, then you will need to pass 2 separate values... or some action to pass the image value to List1. I can look more into it within a few hours for you.

Answer (score 0):

Starting an intent doesn't add data itself. You have to explicitly add the data into the intent.
This can be done by `putExtra` method. This method requires two parameter first being a string which is usually a key. You will be retrieving the data back using this key. Other parameter is a value which can be String, int, long, boolean etc.
Here is an example where value is of string type.

```
in.putExtra("key","value");
```

In your case. In the onItemClick method extract the Contact object and pass its data along with the intent like

```
in.putExtra("id",contact.getId());
```

And in the List1 Activity in onCreate method you can get back the id like this

```
Intent in = getIntent();
int id = in.getIntExtra("id",-1);
```

Here -1 is the default value. Also note that we are using the same key used to put the data into the intent while retrieving it which is "id". Then you can query the data from the DB.